# Load Same ACF Map Twice on Same Page

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I am working on a website: [MetroCRE](http://www.metrocre.com/property/shorewood-commons/) and am trying to use the Google Maps integration with Advanced Custom Fields.

Now the map is working, however due to specific client needs, they want it in one location on mobile, and within the tab selection that exists on desktop.

However, it is not possible to load the Google Map field twice on the same page.

On mobile, the map works, or resizing the browser at all will make it load, but on page load it will not at `>= 768px`

Does anyone know of any way to get past this?

Comment: Are you sure the map is working? Because when I checked it, it shows a blank map.

Comment: If you look at mobile, or resize the page, it loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the map starts working after resize...

From [ACF Website](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/).

Solving the hidden map issue

The Google map API will not work as expected if initialized on a hidden element. When the element is show, the map will not display. This scenario is most likely when using a popup modal.

To solve this problem, simply trigger the ‘resize’ event on the map variable after the map element is visible.

```
// popup is shown and map is not visible
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

So I would add an event when you click a tab Map to trigger the resize. Put the code into acf_google-map.js at the end

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.acf-map').each(function(){

        // create map
        map = new_map( $(this) );

    });

    $('#map-tab').click(function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });

});
```

EDIT:

Because tabs fade in there's animation so put a delay into resize trigger

```
$('#map-tab').click(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: I have posted the code [here.](https://codeshare.io/sn81f)

I have tried to implement your suggestion, but still when I click on the code it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ishio Yes it doesn't work because you're not putting it in the correct place. You should put the code in the acf_google-map.js file at the end after `$('.acf-map').each(function()`. Look at updated answer.

Comment: @Ishio The reason it doesn't work anywhere else is because `map` variable exists only in that file's self executing function. If you try to use anywhere else, it just grabs an HTML element with ID `map` and that of course doesn't do anything for google map refresh.

Comment: Ahhhh, let me try that then. Thank you!

Comment: Putitng that code in there, I return a `render_map is not defined`. I should mention I did not build this site, but just making updates to it.

Comment: @Ishio Did you put the code in correct place? Because looking at the site, I don't see it.

Comment: @Ishio Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114757/discussion-between-thedrot-and-ishio).

Answer (score 1):

While not the best way to go about it, I found the solution to my issue [here](http://www.ceus-now.com/multiple-google-maps-bootstrap-tabs-only-rendering-on-window-resize/).

Turns out adding some CSS to render both tabs but put them off the page will cause it to work as `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` will not work on tab activation.

Below is the CSS I used to get it to work. Works well for responsive.

```
.tab-pane { display: block !important; position: fixed; right: -9999px; width: 100%; }
.tab-pane.active { position: relative; left: 0; }
```

If anyone has a non-CSS solution, please, let me know as the above answer by TheDrot didn't work for me.