# bing maps bootstrap tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bing-maps

I am trying to place a Bing map inside of bootstrap tab.  Maps are only visible on the first tab.  When I navigate to the second tab the map is blank.  It is unclear what obscures the map on the second tab.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type='text/javascript'
            src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap'
            async defer></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function GetMap()
    {
        var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
            credentials: 'key'
        });

        var map2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap2', {
            credentials: 'key'
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <h3>Header</h3>
        <div class="" role="tabpanel" data-example-id="togglable-tabs">
            <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs bar_tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="active"><a href="#android" data-toggle="tab">Android</a></li>
                <li><a href="#microsoft" data-toggle="tab">microsoft</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane in active" id="android">
                    <h3>One Map</h3>
                    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane " id="microsoft">
                    <h3>Two</h3>
                    <div id="myMap2" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because of how the tabs CSS work, you're going to want to include some javascript in there to get this going. I had a similar issue which worked, and you can review the information here but below is the snippet of code I used that worked. [Previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823987/load-same-acf-map-twice-on-same-page)

Essentially what you want to do, and what below does is add a delay trigger to the map when you cause the tab to swap. The map usually won't trigger as the tabs add a `visibility: hidden;` to the elements, and the map won't load from that. So what happens here is causing the map to trigger a resize when the map pane comes into view. You would just need to replace the `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')` with the appropriate calls from Bing.

```
$('#map-tab').click(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: This logic is correct, just call `GetMap()` in the timeout instead.